# Apt: apt update command fails to update

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-jessie, apt

I need help, can anyone solve this problem? My Raspberry Pi can't update and is showing this when I run `sudo apt update`:

[image: sudo apt update output with some signing errors]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using `wget` or a something (even a web browser) after this happens with each of those hosts (eg., just `wget https://repo.mosquito.com`) and edit in the output from that.  Are you using a proxy server or behind an institutional firewall?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text. Instead paste the text output direct into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a problem with your mirror. Even my closest mirror right now is down (ireland).
Maybe this issue could be fixed by changing mirror.

You can change the apt source/ repo by and fix this issue by:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then you edit the first line by adding a # at the beginning.
Add the the end of the line:

```
deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Your file should look like this:

```
   #deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-$
    # Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
 #deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib $
    deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Then Ctrl-x to save + Y
Then :

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
```

The issue could now be fixed

Answer (score 0):

That means that the public key is not identified as trusted key. You need simply to run the following command followed by the key needed:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <pub key>
```